# Difference in relative error when compared MinMaxScaled prediction and target with re-scaled prediction and target

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm running a deep learning model which requires me to scale my dataset. I'm using `scikit-learn`'s `MinMaxScaler`. After I make the prediction, if I compare the prediction with the target column I get a certain relative error. But if I rescale the dataset and the prediction, the relative error increases massively.

For reference, it's not a good model and the error when using the scaled dataset is around 40% and when I re-scale the error jumps to over 60%. I'm also calculating the relative error this way:

```
def calculate_error(prediction, y):
    rel_error = 2 * np.absolute(y - prediction) / (np.absolute(y) + np.absolute(prediction))
    
    return rel_error
```

From this I get the mean and the standard deviation using `numpy`'s `mean()` and `std()` functions. An example is the following

```
predicted_scaled = [0.26652822, 0.2384195, 0.26829958, 0.25697553, 0.28840747]
real_scaled = [0.16201117, 0.37243948, 0.42085661, 0.49534451, 0.23649907]

rel_error.mean() = 44.02%
rel_error.std() = 14.03%

---

predicted_rescaled = [12.012565, 10.503127, 12.107687, 11.499586, 13.187481]
real_rescaled = [6.4, 17.7, 20.3, 24.3, 10.4]

rel_error.mean() = 51.54%
rel_error.std() = 17.8%
```

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it? Furthermore, what's the correct error: the one that compares prediction and target while scaled or the one I get after scaling?

Comment: @Healthcliff - When scaling using MinMaxScaler, are you scaling the predictor/target variable (Y) also? If yes, why is that so?

Comment: @sharathnatraj I thought that was the standard, to scale everything to keep the gradient descent method from exploding. Source: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-improve-neural-network-stability-and-modeling-performance-with-data-scaling/

Comment: That is definitely not the standard when it comes to Machine learning. The article is in the context of deeplearning and my knowledge is limited there. But for machine learning problems, more often that not in my regression problems, I don't scale the Y variable unless required. The gradient descent for Linear regression works just fine even without scaling of Y variable. However, there are scenarios where we do transform "Y" variable lie Box-Cox transformation for better fit. May I know, which machine learning model are you trying to fit here?

Comment: @sharathnatraj This is a deep learning model (I'll edit the post to include this information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your min value in your min/max scaler shifting the shape of your modelled distribution. Let us, for example, take a single datapoint, `pred=0.6, true=0.8`.

Let us calculate your error according to this point without scaling:

```
error = 2*|0.6-0.8|/ (1.4)
error = 2/7 = 0.28
```

Now we can calculate this scaled according to a (randomly-chosen) scaler with a min of 2.2 and max of 10.1:

```
error = 2*|6.94-8.52|/(16.46)
error = 0.19
```

So, this is not an error in the code, but rather the fact that you are calculating a relative error between two *different distributions* which will result in a different value!

In regards to which one is the 'correct' result to display, I would suggest it depends on what you're discussing. If you're conveying the real results, then I would suggest that you use the re-scaled results. If you're conveying model performance then either will suffice.

Also, I think it is important to scale your outputs/inputs as a model will learn better (generally) with scaled outputs/inputs with an activated output (ie. scaling with  a sigmoid of tanh function at the output layer).